# Javascript: Why does this cookie not expire?

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is how I set a cookie

```
function createCookie(name,value,seconds) {
    if (seconds) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

createCookie('CookieName','1',10);
```

It should expire in 10 seconds, right?
When I lookup the cookies in Firefox I see that it is set with the correct expiration time. But even though the cookie has expired it is still there?

**Edit**: I think I figured it out. Firefox just keeps the expired cookie but they don't really exist anymore. Correct?

Comment: i think ff or any user agent can hold on to them, it just won't send it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expired cookies are not deleted right away in firefox. The discussion on [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/983361) seems to suggest firefox requiring a 'clear history' for the cookie to be removed.

If the cookie is expired it should not affect your application, you should be able to check against its expiry time and ignore it.

Edit: There is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576347) for this issue already.